# how to get 6 month of data plus this month's data in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table contains a lot of data for many years and now I want to get the current month data plus past 6 month data. (for example if today was 2016-05-16, I would like to get data from 2015-11-01 00:00:00)

I used this :

```
select * from my_table
where CreatedDate < date_sub(now(),interval 6 month);
```

but it will return from 2015-11-16 plus the time limit data.

What should I use to do this ?

Comment: What does `SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)` return?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the first day of the month that's six months ago:

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01')
```